# Parse Error in Google Tag Manager to track Pardot form submission

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pardot

I'm trying to track form submissions from Salesforce's Pardot via google tag manager. I followed the instructions here:
https://marcloudconsulting.com/support/pardot-form-tracking-gtm/#step-1

The following code is coming up as an error in tag manager. It's telling me: "Error at line 7, character 2: Parse error. primary expression expected."

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("message", function(m) {
  if(m.data.event == "pardot_form_submit") {
    dataLayer.push(event.data);
  }
});
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo with your `script` closing tag.